# Display Image on website

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code which i want to display the picture not the path. It is on php and 
I'm getting the path from a database. I know how to do it on html but not on php

this is my code

```
  echo"<th>ImagePath:</th> <td>".$row['imgPath'] . " </td></tr>";
```

how can i convert it so it shows the image and not the path? and make the heigh and width like 200
Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: can you tell me what you get if you have  `echo $row['imgPath']`. I want full path....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
echo"<th>ImagePath:</th> <td><img src='".$row['imgPath'] . "' width='200' height='200' /> </td></tr>";
```

However see what you get for `echo $row['imgPath']`. I think the path is incorrect and hence you don't see image.

Can you tell me what you get for `echo $row['imgPath']`

Comment: actually the path shows me an image, but it is too big

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo'<th>ImagePath:</th> <td><img src="'.$row['imgPath'] . '"> </td></tr>';
```

**EDIT**

```
echo '<--';
print_r($row);
echo '-->'
```

Then view the page source.

Comment: i keep getting errors with everything i try  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VAR

Comment: nvm it worked, how do i make the image smaller?

Comment: isn't `src="'` should be `src='"`?

Comment: Does this variable `$row['imgPath']` exists. You can check this with the code in the edit.

Comment: @IsraelRodriguez : use width and height as `<img src="dasdfad.jpg" width="200" height="200" />`

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the html from php

```
echo "<Img src='".$row['imgPath'] . "' >";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not show the image with only path for that you need to use the image tag `<img>`

its like the

```
 <img src="url" alt="some_text">
```

try

```
echo'<th>ImagePath:</th> <td><img src="'.$row['imgPath'] . '"> </td></tr>';
```